# How to evaluate each value in a object in React using the .map function

Tags: reactjs, iteration

I have a response that I am returning in my React SPA. The response looks like this below:

[image]

My desire is to loop through this json and evaluate each key's value. I want to replace the "00/00/0000" and null values "-". I figured I could use the .map function but I can seem to find any code samples that will accomplish what I am trying to accomplish. The for loop doesn't work for me neither. I need to look at each value because I don't know which ones will possibly have null or crazy dates. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might wanna have a look at [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: Check whether this is what you want, https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/vYLXByQ  (Look at console for result)..

Comment: This for loop below will give me the key names , but I need to evaluate the values             `for(var key in Object.keys(object1))
{console.log(Object.keys(object1)[key]);}`

Comment: @ManirajMurugan Thank you sooooo much. That is exactly what I was looking for with one problem. It doesn't update the object.

Comment: @Obie_One, I have made an answer that return object.. Please check it..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan thx, I had figured it out based on what you showed initially    `Object.keys(record).map((item) => {
                    if(record[item] == null || record[item] === "" || record[item] == "00/00/0000")
                    {record[item] ="-"}
                 })`

Comment: @Obie_One, Glad to help you.. Do accept the solution if it resolves your issue..

Comment: where would I accept your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Object.keys(obj).map(...)` to iterate the object.
As you need the end result as object you can do the `.map()` to the object and check for the condition and return updated value of each property inside object.

Working **snippet** as follows,

```js
const obj = {
  "empId": "2222",
  "empFName": "Jack",
  "empLName": "Smith",
  "empHireDate": "10/1/2000",
  "empTermDate": "00/00/0000",
  "empHRCode": ""
}

Object.keys(obj).map(item => {
  if(obj[item] && obj[item] !== "00/00/0000"){
    return obj[item];
  } else {
    return obj[item] = "-";
  }
});

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

For sample, if `response` contains the response then;

```js
function mapIt(obj){
 let newObj = {};
 for(let k in obj){ // similar to Object.keys(obj)
   // or your default logic to change the value

   // you could do 
   // if (k == "something"){
   //   do things differently
   // }
   newObj[k] = shinyFilterFunction(obj[k]);
 }
}
```

You could do it in many ways but `for-in` loop looks cleaner to me.

Comment: in your example, k will only provide me the key and I need to look at the key value. If I did newObj[k], that gives me an undefined value which makes sense.

Comment: no by doing `newObj[k] = sth` you are assigning value. if you need to look at the key then check `k` and you need to implement your own logic. Check the comments in the answer that shows how you can check for `k` and do things differently.

Comment: I need to look at the key's "value" not the key itself

Comment: Well you could do `obj[k]` to access the keys value. and in if condition put `obj[k] == 'something'`. The main thing is looping through the keys.